# Issue with synchronization and getting collection count for id generation

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, synchronization, thread-safety

I'm having an issue with nextMessageId(), it should return a new id for each message created. However, every once and a while it doesn't. It returns a value that has been used already, and I can't understand why. I've tried debugging it in the IDE, but it seems to work fine when I step through it.

I'm trying to learn how to work with multiple threads, how to properly synchronize methods, etc. I'm simulating the process of Users sending messages.

Basically each time a block is mined, messages are copied from the buffer to the current block and then the new block is added to blocks Collection. Everything seems to work fine except the nextMessageId(). Any help is appreciated.

I didn't want to post unnecessary code to keep this post as clean as possible, If further information is needed, please let me know.

UserService class:

```
public final class UserService extends Service<User, String> {
    ...

    @Override
    public void submit(String message, User user) {
        synchronized (Blockchain.class) {
            MessageEntry messageEntry = MessageEntry.newInstance(repo.nextMessageId(), message, user);
            repo.postMessage(messageEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

MinerService class:

```
public final class MinerService extends Service<Miner, Long> {
    ...

    public void submit(Long number, Miner miner) {
        if (repo.getCurrentBlock().hash(number).startsWith(repo.prefix())) {
            synchronized (Blockchain.class) {
                if (repo.getCurrentBlock().hash(number).startsWith(repo.prefix())) {
                    repo.createBlock(number, miner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Blockchain.class

```
public class Blockchain {
    ...

    private Deque<Block> blocks;
    private Deque<DataEntry<?>> messageBuffer;
    private Block currentBlock;

    ...

    public long nextMessageId() {
        return blocks.stream()
                .mapToLong(block -> block.getData().size())
                .sum() + messageBuffer.size() + 1L;
    }

    public void postMessage(DataEntry<?> dataEntry) {
        messageBuffer.offerLast(dataEntry);
    }

    public void createBlock(long number, Miner miner) {
        long duration = (new Date().getTime() - currentBlock.getTimestamp()) / 1000;
        Block.ProofOfWork proofOfWork = new Block.ProofOfWork(number, duration, updateN(duration), miner);
        currentBlock.setProofOfWork(proofOfWork);

        if (blocks.offerLast(currentBlock)) {
            currentBlock = generateBlock();
            currentBlock.setData(messageBuffer);
            messageBuffer.clear();
            stateManager.save();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Output of Message after generating 5 blocks:

```
Block:
Created by miner # 4
Id: 1
Timestamp: 1637995160818
Magic number: 6489039085832314491
Hash of the previous block: 
0
Hash of the block: 
7cecb0d73c5bbfa925f2c04fba90778c8431e43dc3abd1b0faf1dbc23400321c
Block data: no messages
Block was generating for 0 seconds
N was increased to 1

Block:
Created by miner # 6
Id: 2
Timestamp: 1637995160897
Magic number: 5017000130559711273
Hash of the previous block: 
7cecb0d73c5bbfa925f2c04fba90778c8431e43dc3abd1b0faf1dbc23400321c
Hash of the block: 
0ff1a96574cd8cf9db8c91eeb436df8efd084582251c081409e43e0f17069d51
Block data: 
1 Charles: Life is good
2 Aramys: How bout' those Dolphins?
3 Evelio: Life is good
4 Armando: I love Java
5 Evelio: I love Java
6 Armando: What is the meaning of life?
7 Aramys: I love basketball
8 Charles: How bout' those Dolphins?
Block was generating for 0 seconds
N was increased to 2

Block:
Created by miner # 3
Id: 3
Timestamp: 1637995160918
Magic number: -4429177738817892095
Hash of the previous block: 
0ff1a96574cd8cf9db8c91eeb436df8efd084582251c081409e43e0f17069d51
Hash of the block: 
007577aca398b8fa711229b95f2abb0f959aa73fbaa8939516ca1bea11a467fa
Block data: no messages
Block was generating for 0 seconds
N was increased to 3

Block:
Created by miner # 5
Id: 4
Timestamp: 1637995160932
Magic number: 2352460595297940125
Hash of the previous block: 
007577aca398b8fa711229b95f2abb0f959aa73fbaa8939516ca1bea11a467fa
Hash of the block: 
00053d5c5b0e958f828c12ae74469fdce1e840334cfa4a431504239133c7c612
Block data: 
9 Evelio: How are you?
Block was generating for 0 seconds
N was increased to 4

Block:
Created by miner # 5
Id: 5
Timestamp: 1637995160951
Magic number: 3338207044781263189
Hash of the previous block: 
00053d5c5b0e958f828c12ae74469fdce1e840334cfa4a431504239133c7c612
Hash of the block: 
000093d155de9a54e2143b97d752b7d57031056ec6eb07b9672c5c0815fd9272
Block data: 
9 Armando: This chat is garbage
10 Charles: Interesting...
11 Aramys: Will I ever make decent money?
Block was generating for 0 seconds
N was increased to 5

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11]
```

EDIT: The issue was that I was not accounting for the DataEntry (messages) being held in the currentBlock. This fixed the issue:

```
public long nextMessageId() {
    return blocks.stream()
            .mapToLong(block -> block.getData().size())
            .sum() + currentBlock.getData().size() + messageBuffer.size() + 1L;
}
```

Comment: Is the `repo` accessed or modified anywhere else in your program? This includes calls to `nextMessageId` or `postMessage` methods. Is this the only place where these are called?

Comment: yes. This is the only place these calls are made.

Comment: The only other class that modifies the repo is the MinerService class which creates new blocks. When a new block is generated, the process is also synchronized on the Blockchain.class

Comment: I added the additional method and class to the question description.

Comment: With every added block, you clear messageBuffer, which is added to the sum of block sizes. When a new block is generated, messageBuffer is reset. Evidence suggests the block size is less that messageBufferSize, so the new ids are smaller.

Comment: Notice **messageBuffer.clear()** in your ```createBlock```.

Comment: its not, i'll post a print out of the blocks and their messages.

Comment: I added print out. Yes messageBuffer clears after copying data to Current block. The setData method of Block class creates a copy of the buffer: new ArrayDeque<>(data)

Comment: the output shows an issue between block 4 and 5. id 9 is duplicated. If it were synchronized correctly that shouldn't be the case. The nextMessageId() counts the size of the collection in each block, so 0 + 8 + 0 + 1 = 9 and we add 1 = 10. So the first message in block 5 should be id 10. But apparently it seems that the message id was generated the id before block 4 was added. I just do not understand why. Do i need to synchronize the creation of the message?

Comment: I tried but that didn't seem to work. I mean, the way I have it now the class should not release the lock on the class until it finishes adding a message to the buffer, or a block to the collection of blocks right? So how is an id being generated before the lock is released?

Comment: This synchronization is broken, as the `repo.getCurrentBlock().hash(number).startsWith(repo.prefix())` test happens outside the `synchronized(Blockchain.class)` block. It doesn’t help to repeat this expression within the block when broken operation did already happen. Besides that, there is no point in writing `new Date().getTime()`, you can simply call `System.currentTimeMillis()` without wrapping it into a `Date` and unwrapping it again.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the input. Could you elaborate a little more on why the synchronization is broken? I understand that the first call is broken as far as synchronization, but my reasoning for this is to first check whether the condition is met, if its not met there is no reason to lock the class, the function just terminates. If the condition is met, then lock the class, and check it again. As far as my output, it seems to be working fine, however I am interested in knowing why, or how, this could cause problems. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Without synchronization, there is no reliable result for the condition evaluation. But even if the condition happens to evaluate to the correct result, there is no guaranty that the condition doesn’t change before you enter the `synchronized` block, as nothing stops other threads from changing the state right at this point. Yes, it may happen to do the desired thing in 999 of 1000 cases. Or even 999999 of 1000000 cases. It’s not predictable.

Comment: I see. But if the values used in the condition are only changed when there is a lock in place, then you wouldn't be able to enter the synchronized block until that lock is released, and the second conditional would occur only after the values were already updated.

Comment: The idea of the double check locking pattern came from getInstance() method of a singleton class I saw while researching online about how to make a thread safe singletons. I  also read on earlier java versions there was an issue with this algo due to compiler reordering, but I don't know if this is still the case today.

Comment: @Holger, well thank you for the input. I'm still not completely convinced about the synchronization issue, but I will try to come up with a better solution. None of this is for production, just playing around trying to learn some new things and better understand working with threads and synchronization. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Every reasonable article about double checked locking will tell you that it still doesn’t work, unless you can turn the condition into a single volatile read, which a) doesn’t apply to your condition and b) destroys the hypothetical benefit of skipping the `synchronized` block. Further, you still miss the point that your condition evaluation outside the `synchronized` block can break in various ways, spurious `NullPointerException`s, for example. Or just evaluate to `false` when it should be `true`. Since you skip the `synchronized` block on `false`, there is no re-evaluation in that case.

Comment: @Holger, ok thank you. I see how that can be a possibility. Especially the case where I get a false evaluation when it should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> The nextMessageId() counts the size of the collection in each block

NextMessageId:

```
    public long nextMessageId() {
        return blocks.stream()
                .mapToLong(block -> block.getData().size())
                .sum() + messageBuffer.size() + 1L;
    }
```

Didn’t you also add an additional `messagebuffer` size?

And in your `createBlock` method, you will clear this buffer. So the ID has become smaller again.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not follow. If I have 10 items in the messageBuffer, and then a block is created. those 10 items are copied to the block and cleared from the buffer. so the block now has 10 elements and the messageBuffer has 0 elements. the 10 + 0 is still 10. it hasn't gotten smaller.

Comment: I see whats happening now. You are right. I add the messages to the currentBlock. Actually that block isn't added to the collection until it is mined. So I am not counting the messages in the current block, and I need to.

Comment: public long nextMessageId() {  
    return blocks.stream()  
        .mapToLong(block -> block.getData().size())  
        .sum() + currentBlock.getData().size() + messageBuffer.size() + 1L;  
}

Comment: no need, i wouldn't have noticed the issue had you and @burak-serdar not mentioned the id getting smaller again. Although not entirely accurate, It lead to the solution.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand the context of your problem, but if you can solve it, that's fine...